# python manage.py runserver: TypeError: argument 1 must be str not WindowsPath

Tags: python, django

I am following up a django tutorial and I have just installed django using `pip install django=2.1` and it was successfully installed then I created a project using `django-admin startproject App .` after that I am trying to runserver using `python manage.py runserver` and I am getting a `TypeError: argument 1 must be str not WindowsPath`.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x02AC2D20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in
 wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver
.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442
, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 1
8, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49,
 in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 209
, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 6
1, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 4
4, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor(
))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 25
5, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 23
2, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 21
6, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 19
4, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\WebDev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
 159, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not WindowsPath
```

here is settings.py:

```
    from pathlib import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'App.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'App.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Am i missing something? Please help!
Also stackoverflow is not allowing me to add more info because it says my post is mostly code.

Comment: conn = Database.connect(**conn_params) - Looks like the connection parameters are not passed accurately.

Comment: @SRDJ I have added App/settings.py but I removed all the comments because SO is not accepting my question It says your question is mostly code.

Comment: Did you try running the initial Django migrations like - python manage.py migrate

Comment: I am not using Windows. So, I can't replicate the issue at my end but your settings look fine to me.

Comment: @SRDJ No, I am following up a tutorial and I have no idea about it, If you could give me instructions that could help.

Comment: Additionally, you can have a look at this tutorial - https://dev.to/vishnureddys/how-to-create-your-first-django-app-on-windows-dap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is here

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

`BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'` returns a Pathlib object(`WindowsPath` if you are using windows otherwise `PosixPath`), where as `NAME` actually expect a string. So change from

```
BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3
```

to

```
str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')
```

in order to get a string representation of `Path` object.